# .joinedAt proprety always returning undefined in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

im trying to make a userinfo command right now on my discord bot. one of the fields is the time that the user joined the server.

heres my code

```
module.exports.run = async (Client, msg, args, UserDataBase, messages, commands_ran) => {
    let user = msg.guild.member(msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.guild.members.get(args[0]))

    if(!user) {
        user = msg.author
    }else {
         user = user.user
    }

    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle('**User info**')
    .setThumbnail(user.avatarURL)
    .addField('Name:', user.username,true)
    .addField('Tag:', `#${user.discriminator}`,true)
    .addField('Date Joined:', user.createdAt)
    .addField('Joined Server:', user.joinedAt)
    msg.channel.send(embed)
}
```

it always returns Undefined in the [final product](https://drizzy.is-terrible.com/EYEI72)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User` objects don't have a `joinedAt` property because a User is not specific to any server. The representation of a user *in a server* is a `GuildMember`, which is what you're getting in the first line of your function.

You could just remove the part that forces it to be a User object and your code should work due to discord.js adding getters for all User properties on the `GuildMember`.

```
module.exports.run = async (Client, msg, args, UserDataBase, messages, commands_ran) => {
    let user = msg.guild.member(msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.guild.members.get(args[0]))

    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle('**User info**')
    .setThumbnail(user.avatarURL)
    .addField('Name:', user.username,true)
    .addField('Tag:', `#${user.discriminator}`,true)
    .addField('Date Joined:', user.createdAt)
    .addField('Joined Server:', user.joinedAt)
    msg.channel.send(embed)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`user` doesn't have any joinedAt property, so you will need to use `GuildMember`.
This can be obtained by member = msg.guild.member(user)
and then `.addField('Joined at:' member.joinedAt)`